# SQL Server restore the schema only

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

We have a database with test data in it the Dev environment we used to develop. and another DB in production, I want to refresh only the schema from production to Dev environment, but I need all the data that is in Dev environment.

Is there a way to copy the database schema alone from Production and refresh the schema in Dev without losing the Dev environment data?.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried any approach? Why don't you just create missing schema in to Dev Env..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using schema compare from SQL Server Data tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) from Redgate.  Its a paid product but if its just a one off you could use the trial version

Answer (score 1):

Schema compare can be done with SDDT. Make a data schema project, import schema from production, generate change script to develop.

That said, your setup is broken - you should have deployable change scripts, or how do you expect to move changes back in an orderly fashion?